# How to track down undefined method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error, "NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #" and not sure how to track down how my 'user' is not defined.

My user.rb is this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My property.rb is this:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And my migration file is this:

```
class AddUserIdToProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :properties, :user_id, :interger
    add_index :properties, :user_id
  end
end
```

And here's my controller

```
 def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)

      if @property.save
        redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.'
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
```

It seems to be breaking when in my properties_controller.rb I change this:

```
 def new
    @property = Property.new
  end
```

to this:

```
def new
    @property = current_user.property.build
  end
```

Here's my error logs

```
Started GET "/properties/new" for ::1 at 2015-04-27 00:45:49 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PropertiesController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `property' for #<User:0x007f9fa6f3e1c8>):
  app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:12:in `new'


  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (6.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (50.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (33.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.1.2/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (7
```

Comment: Are you using your 'user' in one of your views?  For example: `<%= property.user_id %>`

Comment: And the meesage that s giving your that error? Have a look in your logs... you will find the error that you list above (somewhere), and about 30 lines of scrolling text (all filenames with numbers after them) after that... it's called a stacktrace. copy/paste the first 5-10 lines of that and edit and add it to your question (do *not* copy it into comments as formatting is really crap here).

Comment: Maybe your problem (if your migration ran successfully) is that you have not specified What the associations are between the User and Property classes. In this case a Property belongs_to :user. Don't forget to add has_one/has_many on the User model.

Comment: I was typing the above comment on my phone while the edit was being made. After reading the edit,the above is your problem. I'm on a phone and cannot give proper answer.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like: `@property = Property.new({:user_id => @property.user_id})`  ?  Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking your migration its look like you have to add this,

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :property
end
```

Comment: Because the Property class has a user_id column, it should be: belongs_to :user. (The has_one or has_many goes in the User class).

Comment: Don't forget to change :property to :user  :)